# Capture all the telemetry to azure application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, telemetry

I want to capture all the requests in application insights. The below example given by Microsoft is confusing, didn't mention whether 'N' is a requests to capture or the total requests. Should I give 100 percent or 1 percent to capture all of them?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.SamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <!-- Set a percentage close to 100/N where N is an integer. -->
      <!-- E.g. 50 (=100/2), 33.33 (=100/3), 25 (=100/4), 20, 1 (=100/100), 0.1 (=100/1000) -->
      <SamplingPercentage>100</SamplingPercentage>
    </Add>
```

Comment: Hi, set 100 means capture 100% requests. set 10 means capture 10 requests if there are 100 request in total.  That's what sampling works : ) So you need to set 100 or don't set it. By default, all the requests will be captured by app insights.

Comment: Thanks @TinyWang, one correction is that it is not capturing all the requests by default.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15581227/tiny-wang). Posting your comment discussion as answer to help other community members.

> Setting `SamplingPercentage` 100 means, it capture 100% requests (all
> the requests are captured). Setting it to 10 means, it captures 10
> requests if there are 100 request in total.